# How can users run a python script without installing python on their local machines and without converting the script into an executable?

Tags: python, azure, central

I have a tool written in python that we developed in house. Several users are running this tool, however they are not familiar with python or programming, so we developed a GUI alongside for them to run the code. 
So far we have used Miniconda located on the server (which was on premises) and users started the GUI/tool using a batch file (RUNNER.bat) and accessing the python in Miniconda on the server. The batch file looks like below, where gmain.py starts the main program.

```
cd .\SRC
T:\server-path-name-where-Miniconda-is-located\Miniconda3A\python gmain.py
pause
```

Now we have moved to Azure server. Using the same batch file now takes ages to start the program. Only if the Miniconda3A is locally on every users C-drive it works. However I would prefer it to be central so I can update packages or manage changes and make sure everyone has access to the same python version. 
What is the reason, why it is so much slower on Azure server vs on-premises and is there a way around installing it on every computer? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is Miniconda3A installed on a VM and the users have mapped a network drive to that VM?

Comment: yes, everyone has a mapped network drive where Miniconda is located.

Comment: Are you using File Storage File Share functionality for mapping the network drive?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with this, I think they just use the functionality provided by windows file explorer to map the drive.